# Trouble with PHP if else logic and variables

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

So, I have a couple of variables in PHP, and they are generated from different places.  $new_ip comes from the following command:

```
$new_ip = file_get_contents('http://www.ipaddresscheck.comlu.com/ip.php');
```

And the $old_ip comes from:

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ip ORDER BY  id DESC LIMIT 1');
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql );
$old_ip = $row['current_ip'];
```

My problem is, I am getting incorrect results from:

```
if ($old = $new)
{
$different = '1';    
}
else {
$different = '2';  
}
echo $different;
```

I ALWAYS get 2, wether the IPs are the same or not; if I use '==' as the comparison, I ALWAYS get 1.

When I run the following code, I get the following output:
    var_dump($old_ip);
    var_dump($new_ip);

Output

string(15) "123.123.123.123" string(167) "184.6.216.163 "

Are the variables different types?  If So, can I make them the same so I am only comparing the IP and not the type?  If the IPs are the same I should get '1' and if they are different, I should get '2', right?

Comment: You are getting `string(167)` on `var_dump($new_ip)`? Are you sure there is nothing else in that string as `184.6.216.163` is only 13.

Comment: btw. you are using a deprecated extension `mysql`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is lurking here:

```
string(15) "123.123.123.123" string(167) "184.6.216.163 "
                                    ^^^
```

The address retrieved from your database is coming along with 154 unwanted characters. `trim()` both strings and then do the comparison.

Oh - and you should really shorten the field that stores the IP address. 15 characters should do.

Comment: The number on the left is coming from the database, the one on the right, is from the $new_ip = file_get_contents('http://www.ipaddresscheck.comlu.com/ip.php');

Comment: @JustinMarmorato Sorry - my mistake. I lost track of where the values were coming from in the midst of a phone call. Nevertheless, the value I highlighted is still way too long. Take a look at the code that creates it.

Answer (score 2):

Code

```
if ($old = $new) // you are using assignment operator here
{
   $different = '1';    
}
```

Should be

```
if ($old == $new) //Equal to operator
{
   $different = '1';    
}
```

Also **confirm** the variable names  are 
**$old and $new** or **$old_ip and $new_ip**

Comment: Quoted from the OP: `if I use '==' as the comparison, I ALWAYS get 1.`. So there is more to it.

Comment: it should be $old_ip == $new_ip... you dont have $old variable in the code provided its $old_ip and $new_ip

Answer (score 1):

- Assignment ( `=` ): Assigns the value on the right to the variable on the left
- Equality ( `==` ): Checks if the left and right values are equal
- Identical ( `===` ): Checks if the left and right values are equal AND identical (same variable type)

  Example:

  ```
  $a = 1; // Sets the value of $a as the integer 1
  $b = TRUE; // Sets the value of $b to the boolean TRUE
  if ($a == $b){
  echo 'a is equal to b.';
  }

  if ($a === $b){ // compare VALUE and data type: if $a(integer) === $b(boolean)
  echo 'a is identical and equal to b.';
  }

  if ($a = $b){ 
  echo '$b value to variable $a';
  }
  ```

In your code i noticed a problem. A space is there in second IP address. so

```
string(15) "123.123.123.123" string(167) "184.6.216.163 "
                                                       ^
```

1. Trim both IP address.
2. If not work, then convert it to other datatype and compare.(Just for debugging purpose. :))

Comment: how do I strip the whitespace? Ive tried $old_ip3 = str_replace(' ', '', $old_ip2);
$new_ip3 = str_replace(' ', '', $new_ip2);

Comment: Build-in function are there to trim PHP string. $old_ip2 = trim($old_ip);

Comment: Ive tried trim and str_replace.  I can't seem to get the extra hundred something characters out of that variable.  Is there a way I cam limit the size of the variable?  That would be a start, then I would only have to figure out how to deal with the space when the IP is not 3.3.3.3, say 2.3.1.3.

Comment: You could use regular expression to strip your IP from the rest. Use `preg_match()` to find a match for a IP address and return the match, or use `preg_replace()` and replace all unwanted characters.

Answer (score 0):

OLD :

```
if ($old = $new){
   $different = '1';    
}
```

New Correct :

```
if ($old == $new){
   $different = '1';    
}
```

you are using (=) assignment operation in the place of comparison operation.

Comment: I actually did that before I posted the question.  The question was a typo.  But regardless, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the behaviour is normal because you are using `$old` and `$new` both are unset.

```
$new_ip = file_get_contents('http://www.ipaddresscheck.comlu.com/ip.php');

$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ip ORDER BY  id DESC LIMIT 1');
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql );
$old_ip = $row['current_ip'];
```

The next code will always give 2 because $new is unset. What you are doing here is assigning `$old` the value of `$new` and since `$new` is unset `$old = $new` will always be false.

```
if ($old = $new)
{
    $different = '1';    
} else {
    $different = '2';  
}
echo $different;
```

In the next example you are actually comparing `$old` and `$new`. Since both are unset the expression `$old == $new` will always be true.

```
if ($old == $new)
{
    $different = '1';    
} else {
    $different = '2';  
}
echo $different;
```

What you need to do is using the right vars and trim them.

```
// get new ip and trim white spaces
$new_ip = trim(file_get_contents('http://www.ipaddresscheck.comlu.com/ip.php'));
// get the old ip
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ip ORDER BY  id DESC LIMIT 1');
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql );
$old_ip = $row['current_ip'];

if ($old_ip == $new_ip)
{
    $different = '1';    
} else {
    $different = '2';  
}
echo $different;
```

I am not trimming white spaces on `$old_ip` because I guess that you will be using `$new_ip` to update your database and since `$new_ip` is already trimmed we can be sure that `$old_ip` has no white spaces.

You should always have php warnings enabled when coding!
It would have popped you a warning because you used unset vars.

PS : note that this code will only work as expected if `file_get_contents()` returns a IP with white spaces, the output could be different (error output, not able to detect ip correctly, ... etc)